# how to send mail when load balancer backend service become unhealthy in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using GCP Load Balancer and set three backend services in one Load Balancer.

When I set an instance group with two instances and one backend service how do I send a warnning mail when the number of healthy instances in a group falls below certain threshold (two for example) like in AWS "HealthyHostCount" ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - you want to set some sort of alert when one of the instances in the group will be unresponsive ?

Comment: thank you for your answer. i add image picture for my question.

Comment: hei, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you like to create backend alert policy for http LB for health check then you could set ip by following this document [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Metrics Explorer in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) provides a powerful tool for monitoring and analyzing metrics across various services and resources.

To get started, follow these steps:

1. **Navigate to Metrics Explorer**: Go to the GCP console and select the desired project. In the left-hand menu, under the "Monitoring" section, click on "Metrics Explorer."
2. **Choose Resource and Metric**: In the Metrics Explorer interface, select the appropriate resource type, such as "Compute Engine Instance Group" under the "Compute Engine" category. Then, choose the "Instance Group" metric from the available list.
3. **Configure Filters and Aggregation**: Customize the metric retrieval by adding filters and selecting the desired aggregation function. For instance, you might want to filter based on a specific region or instance group name and aggregate the metric by average or maximum value.
4. **Visualize and Validate**: After applying the filters and aggregation, Metrics Explorer will display a graph or table showcasing the selected metric's behavior over time. Use this visualization to ensure you are fetching the correct data.
5. **Create an Alert**: Once you have verified the metric's accuracy, you can proceed to create an alert based on its values. Click on the "Create Alerting Policy" button on the top-right corner of the Metrics Explorer interface. Configure the conditions for triggering the alert, such as a threshold value or a specific duration of sustained metric behavior.